# PHP - Count how many days ago

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, count

In my database I have a bunch of Last Login dates for my users. They are written like this:
`Last Login: Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CEST`
And:
`Last Login: Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CET`

So both `CEST` and `CET` at the end can occur.

What I'd like to do is however, is to see how many days ago that was (rounded). Is there any way I can do that with this format? It has to be in this format. I'd like to echo out the following on my website:

`Last Login: Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CEST (46 days ago)`

I can't find any examples for this format. Most of them are in milliseconds or so. Is this even possible?

I only need the days. Hours and minutes are not important.

It's basically this:
`$date=date('d M Y');`

Comment: Is all the entry will have same format i.e., `Last Login: Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CEST` ?

Comment: Yes, or "CET" at the end. It varies. But all in the database have the same format. I think first step would be to just get the "Apr 08 2015" part, and then convert that somehow

Comment: Writing answer for you :)

Comment: By the way, "Last Login:" is not included in the date. Thats just in my echo. In the database, the date looks like this only: `Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CET`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

Remove the Last part of your date i.e., `CET` or `CE`

```
$Date = substr($Date, 0, strpos($Date, " "));
```

It will the character after last spaces

**Step 2**

Find the Difference between current date and the extracted date by

```
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

And here's the entire code :

```
<?php
$Date = "Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CES";
$Date = substr($Date, 0, strpos($Date, " CE"));
$now  = date('Y-m-d');
$datetime1 = new DateTime($Date);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($now);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

If you want to print the different message if there is 0 days difference then just check if there is `0` day difference and handle it

```
if ($interval->format('%R%a')=="-0")
{
    echo 'Last Login Today';
}
else
{
    echo $interval->format('%R%a');
}
```

Comment: That works! But how can I remove the "Last Login:" part? That's just in my echo. The actual dates are only: `Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CET` for example

Comment: If you see the answer i will remove the entire part and have only the content between first `:` and `,` i.e., `Apr 08 2015` So here the `Last Login` is removed. You saying about this one or what ??

Comment: In the $Date you wrote the string with "Last Login:" I only want: `$Date = "Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CES"`

Comment: So, in your database you will have only this `Apr 08 2015, 22:53:49 CES` ?

Comment: Yes, but I echo it on my website with "last login"

Comment: Thank you so much! :) By the way, is there a way to see if it's 0 days.  And it it's 0 days ago print "Last Login: today" ... Like: `if ($interval->format('%R%a days') == 0) { echo "Last Login: today"; }` Would this work? I don't know if it's an integer

Comment: I see your new code, but it echo "30 days", it was "46" before no?

Comment: Yes, just a min, i am checking it .. wil update in few seconds

Comment: Thanks I have updated the answer.. Now it should give the same result :)

Comment: You are amazing! I wish I can be as good as you one day! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also do you want to print something else if there is 0 days different ?

Comment: I fixed it, I just checked if $interval == 0, then I echo "Last Login: Today" :)